# My data set has a column "SalSat" with categorical data. I want to change that column content to 0 and 1 for my logistic regression practice

Tags: python, dictionary, logistic-regression

My data set has a column `SalSat` with categorical data. I want to change that column content to 0 and 1 for my logistic regression practice

I am using this code:-

```
data_copy['SalSat']=data_copy['SalSat'].map({'>50K':0,'<=50K':1}) 
     print(data_copy['SalSat'])
```

Please Help

Comment: what's the error that you are getting?

Comment: i am getting all NaN values instead of 0 and 1.

Comment: Can anyone please help i am stuck.